# KRL: Parsing string as JSON

Tags: json, krl

After using `http:get()`, I receive back a string from `pick`ing the "content" from the hash:

```
response = http:get(webservice_url, {"key1": value1, "key2": value2});
json_resp = response.pick("$..content");
```

However, since `json_resp` is a string and not an actual JSON object, I can't run a command like this:

```
value = json_resp.pick("$..string");
```

Is there a way to tell KRL that I want to parse `json_resp` as JSON? An `eval()` or something, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`decode()`](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Decode) operator does just what you want. It operates on a JSON string, attempting to convert it to a native KRL object. Note that KRL also has [`encode()`](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Encode) which operates on a native KRL object and returns a JSON string representation of that object.

```
response = http:get(webservice_url, {"key1": value1, "key2": value2});
json_resp = response.pick("$..content").decode();
value = json_resp.pick("$..string");
// will work since json_resp is now a native KRL object
```